# Using VBA to change body content of an outlook 2010 email that was sent

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I sent an email using Outlook 2010 and after sending the email it was stored in the default Sent Items folder.

I would like to use VBA code to search for a string in the recently sent email and replace the string with a different string.

Can you suggest code that would do it?

Comment: Find & Replace Text - `Item.Body = Replace(Item.Body, "BlaBla", "Replacement text Here")`  GoodLuck

Comment: Thanks. How do I get to the recently sent email? This is actually what I did not know how to code correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190000/replace-a-string-in-a-sent-email

Comment: if the answer was helpful could you mark accept, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[GetDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSent)
```

[Find & Replace Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953%28v=office.11%29.aspx) -

```
Item.Body = Replace(Item.Body, "BlaBla", "Replacement text Here")
```